# Get value from OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, double

I have one channel matrix in my program,  with next definition:

```
matchingResult.create(result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1);
```

It is not a matrix of colours.
I use *minMaxLoc* method to find of positions of the min and max values:

```
double minValue;
double maxValue;
cv::Point minLocation;
cv::Point maxLocation;          
cv::minMaxLoc(_matchingMap, &minValue, &maxValue, &minLocation, &maxLocation);
```

This method returns correct values:

> MinValue: -287909 MaxValue: 682182 MinLocation: [5, 1] MaxLocation:
>   [4, 2]

If I print the matrix into *cout* I'll get same result.

But I can't get same value from the matrix by using the location of max value (maxLocation), or change value of the max.
If I try to get value:

```
double value = _matchingMap.at<double>(maxLocation);
std::cout<<"Value for "<<maxLocation << " is "<<value << std::endl;
```

I'll get something strange:

> Value for [4, 2] is -1.08215e+39

I want to change values in matrix by using row/coll coordinates, but I do something wrong. I can't find error, may smb can show me the correct way.

How to iterate a matrix I've seen [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#performance-difference)

Comment: Your matrix is 32FC1, so you need to use   `at<float>`

Comment: thank you, it's helped for me, can you post answer with explanation for 32 bits and 64 bits architectures? My wrong was, that I've found that flat is 4 bits. I should be more careful for internet resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize a Mat with 32FC1 you allocate cells of 32bits, which are represented by `float` in C.  In order to work with a matrix of `double` which are 64 bit floating point values, you need to use  64FC1.

So, either change the matrix to doubles, or use   `at<float>`